# Model::load($params['id']) fails with Fatal error

Tags: magento

**local/Nofrills/Booklayout/controllers/ModelController.php**

```
<?php
class Nofrills_Booklayout_ModelController  extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
     $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
     $model = Mage::getModel('nofrills_booklayout/testmodel');
     echo("Loading the blogpost with an ID of ".$params['id']);
     $model->load($params['id']);
     $data = $model->getData();
     var_dump($data);
    }

}
?>
```

**local/Nofrills/Booklayout/Model/Testmodel.php**

```
<?php
class Nofrills_Booklayout_Model_Testmodel extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
  protected function _construct()
  {
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('nofrills_Booklayout/testmodel');
  }
}
?>
```

**local/Nofrills/Booklayout/etc/Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Nofrills_Booklayout>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Nofrills_Booklayout>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <nofrills_booklayout>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Nofrills_Booklayout</module>
                <frontName>nofrills_booklayout</frontName>
            </args>
        </nofrills_booklayout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <nofrills_booklayout>
            <class>Nofrills_Booklayout_Block</class>
        </nofrills_booklayout>
    </blocks>
    <models>
        <nofrills_booklayout>
            <class>Nofrills_Booklayout_Model</class>
             <resourceModel>nofrills_booklayout_resource</resourceModel> 
        </nofrills_booklayout>
         <nofrills_booklayout_resource>
            <class>Nofrills_Booklayout_Model_Resource</class>
         </nofrills_booklayout_resource>
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <nofrills_booklayout>
            <class>Nofrills_Booklayout_Helper</class>
        </nofrills_booklayout>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

When following controller action is executed "http://myserver.com/magento/nofrills_booklayout/model/index/id/1" Code line Mage::getModel() in ModelController.php returns valid object. Testmodel.php is there in local/Nofrills/Booklayout/Model/Testmodel.php.
After execution of code line $model->load($params['id']); the expected error is :

```
Warning: include(Nofrills/Booklayout/Model/Resource/Testmodel.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file ...
```

**The actual error displayed is**

```
Loading the blogpost with an ID of 1 Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 225 Call Stack: 0.0119 660352 1. {main}() /var/www/magento/index.php:0 0.0144 1219280 2. Mage::run(???, ???, ???) /var/www/magento/index.php:87 0.0205 3044928 3. Mage_Core_Model_App->run(???) /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php:684 1.1513 16921392 4. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354 1.1652 18830664 5. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(???) /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:172 1.1694 19696808 6. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch(???) /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php:250 1.2951 23809000 7. Nofrills_Booklayout_ModelController->indexAction() /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:418 29.6125 24956920 8. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(???, ???) /var/www/magento/app/code/local/Nofrills/Booklayout/controllers/ModelController.php:9
```

During debugging I noticed that function  **_getResourceModelFactoryClassName($modelClass)**  returns false.

Can some help to Identify the problem?

Comment: Does the file `app/local/Nofrills/Booklayout/Model/Resource/Testmodel.php` exist?

Comment: NO It doesn't exist, that why the error I am expecting is " failed to open stream:"

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I misread the question. Anyway, I'm not sure but shouldn't it be `$this->_init('nofrills_booklayout/testmodel');` instead of `$this->_init('nofrills_Booklayout/testmodel');` in your model constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento by default loads a Model's backing resource using the string you pass in the model's constructor as an argument to its `_init` method. In your case you passed `'nofrills_Booklayout/testmodel'`.

`Mage_Core_Model_Config` uses this string to retrieve the xml node of the model's module's `config.xml` that "represents" the module's sub-directory where resource classes are located. `Mage_Core_Model_Config::_getResourceModelFactoryClassName` explodes that string in two parts (respectively the part before and the part after the slash).

The first part is used for the aforementioned xml node. Since `_getResourceModelFactoryClassName` cannot find a valid node it returns `false` (which, as you already figured out, is the cause for the error *«Call to a member function load() on a non-object»*.

If you replace

```
$this->_init('nofrills_Booklayout/testmodel');
```

with:

```
$this->_init('nofrills_booklayout/testmodel');
```

you get the error you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling model wrong way if you want to call your model then call

```
 $model = Mage::getModel('booklayout/testmodel');
     echo("Loading the blogpost with an ID of ".$params['id']);
     $model->load($params['id']);
```

if you want to call model then it's syntax will be

```
$model = Mage::getModel('MODULE_NAME/MODEL_NAME');
```

Let me know if you want to any query

Comment: My code gives the model object. I have verified that object is created. What I don't get is the Resource.